# Get all output to console from a Process in java

Tags: java, process, wrapper

I'm working on an application to act as a 'wrapper' around another another application, in this case I'm working on a wrapper in java to go around a TF2 server. However, I'm running into a rather odd issue with getting the output from the console to appear. Even if I redirect the error stream so that it will go with the input stream, the output to console will cut off after a certain point. I can connect to the server in TF2, so I know for a fact that it's launched.

The code for the wrapper:

```
public class TF2Wrapper {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder("./srcds_run","+map pl_badwater","+port 27015","2>&1");
    process.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process server = process.start();
    BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));
    String s;
    while((s = inputStream.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

It will read the output up until the second time this line appears: 'Calling BreakpadMiniDumpSystemInit',then no further console output appears, or atleast is picked up by the application.

Is there anything I can do to fix this or is that not possible?

Edit: My guess is it has something to do with the buffering, as trying to do this with python works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using BufferedReader  use ByteArrayOutputStream

```
    public class Example {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            ByteArrayOutputStream arrayOutputStream = null;
//in case of window
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("ipconfig");

            try {
                Process process = builder.start();
                inputStream = process.getInputStream();
                byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                int size = 0;
                arrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                while ((size = inputStream.read(b)) != -1) {
                    arrayOutputStream.write(b, 0, size);
                }

                System.out.println(new String(arrayOutputStream.toByteArray()));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (inputStream != null)
                        inputStream.close();
                    if (arrayOutputStream != null)
                        arrayOutputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.getStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
    }
```

Comment: This didn't do anything. Now it doesn't even output anything.

Comment: @VoidWhisperer please see the changes now i have added full class.And for TF2 server is your command is running ? if yes what is the status code you are getting u can get the status code by this int x = process.exitValue(); if x=0 then ur command run successfully.In your case may be command is not running

Comment: With the exact code above it still prints absolutely nothing.